# Eliminating subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_A` (
  `id_a` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
  `ref` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `colA` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            :
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_a`),
  KEY `INDEX_A1` (`ref`)
  KEY `INDEX_A2` (`colA`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE `TABLE_B` (
  `id_b` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
             :
  PRIMARY KEY (`ib_b`),
  KEY `INDEX_B1` (`ref`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I have a query to these tables as below. But this query is slow.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM TABLE_A AS T1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ref,MAX(status) as status FROM TABLE_B GROUP BY ref )
AS T2 ON T1.ref = T2.ref
WHERE T2.status = ? AND T1.colA = ?
```

I tried `explain` on this SQL, and the result is below.

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_key | key      | key_len | ref    | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | T1         | ref    | INDEX_A2     | INDEX_A2 | 152     | const  |   136 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL         | NULL     | NULL    | NULL   | 29400 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | TABLE_B    | index  | NULL         | INDEX_B1 | 152     | NULL   | 36223 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

I think I have to eliminate subquery to improve my query.

How can I do the same thing without subquery? Or do I have other methods for improvement?

Comment: I thing that is likely a problem is that you are doing a left join and then filterring on values of B table: T2.status = ? . Try moving this condition inside your sub query.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But your suggestion has no effect because more than 90% of TABLE_B matches with status = ?

Comment: I think you can improve the subquery performance by changing `INDEX_B1` to `(ref, status)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  t1.*
from table_a as t1
  inner join table_b as t2
    on t1.ref = t2.ref
  left outer join table_b as t3
    on t3.ref = t2.ref
    and t3.status > t2.status
where t3.status is null;
```

[This](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/) has a good explanation of why the above should work.

Comment: You'll need to add 'WHERE T2.status = ? AND T1.colA = ?' back in.  I forgot to include it.

Comment: If you actually included the bones of the explanation in your answer, then it would be perfect. The linked article can be removed any time, thus rendering your answer a lot less useful, than it is now.

Comment: Point taken.  Perhaps when I have time I will go back and add in my own explanation.  Unfortunately, I'm unlikely to put things anywhere near as clearly as Baron does in his post.